# How to remove required action "Configure OTP" from Keycloak Admin Client user registration

Tags: spring, configuration, keycloak

I'm using spring to create users with keycloak admin client. In my `UserService` I'm only specifying 2 required actions: Verify Email & Update Password

```java
    public String create(UserRequest request) {
        UserRepresentation userRepresentation = new UserRepresentation();
        userRepresentation.setEnabled(true);
        userRepresentation.setUsername(request.getUsername());
        userRepresentation.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
        userRepresentation.setLastName(request.getLastName());
        userRepresentation.setEmail(request.getEmail());

        CredentialRepresentation credentialRepresentation = new CredentialRepresentation();
        credentialRepresentation.setTemporary(true);
        credentialRepresentation.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
        credentialRepresentation.setValue(request.getCode());

        userRepresentation.setCredentials(List.of(credentialRepresentation));
        userRepresentation.setRequiredActions(
            List.of(
                UserModel.RequiredAction.VERIFY_EMAIL.name(),
                UserModel.RequiredAction.UPDATE_PASSWORD.name()
            ));

        Response response = keycloak.realm(this.realm).users().create(userRepresentation);
        if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL)
            return CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response);
        return null;
    }
```

Yet, after creation, I'm getting 3 required actions in admin console: Configure OTP, Verify Email & UpdatePassword.
I've seen some articles talking about flows but the newer Version of Admin Console looks almost nothing like the one in the tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user has unexpected Required Actions on creation, you should check if that action is configured as a "default action" in the realm.

For this, navigate to your realm in the admin console, click "Authentication" on the left sidebar, and then click the "Required Actions" Tab.

There you should see a list of all required actions that are available. The first switch for each means that the required action is enabled for that realm. The second switch means that the required action will be automatically set for all new users created in that realm.